# VSTS task "Publish Test Results" is not able to access $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) for test results

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, msbuild-task, azure-pipelines-build-task

The search folder path is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) below is the error

```
==============================================================================
2017-07-12T17:22:40.7168687Z Task         : Publish Test Results
2017-07-12T17:22:40.7168687Z Description  : Publish Test Results to VSTS/TFS
2017-07-12T17:22:40.7168687Z Version      : 2.0.1
2017-07-12T17:22:40.7168687Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-07-12T17:22:40.7168687Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613742)
2017-07-12T17:22:40.7168687Z ==============================================================================
2017-07-12T17:22:41.1214206Z ##[warning]Failed to publish test results: Access to the path 'd:\a\1\s\DtlTestResults.trx' is denied.
2017-07-12T17:22:41.1244177Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2017-07-12T17:22:41.1244177Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2017-07-12T17:22:41.1244177Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Test Results DtlTestResults.trx
```

Comment: Please check if you have enough access build/publish the test results. Besidea, do you queued the build on private agent? Can you show the settings of Publish Test Results task and what's the build log after you set `system.debug` to `true` in variables Tab?

Comment: Thanks Marina,I am using hosted agent, here is the log

Comment: Search folder = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Comment: Search folder = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), the log exceeds the length allowed so copying the error part here,    

2017-07-14T18:39:50.4442496Z ##[warning]Failed to publish test results: Access to the path 'd:\a\1\s\DtlTest.trx' is denied.
2017-07-14T18:39:50.4462454Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[results.publish type=VSTest;mergeResults=false;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=d:\a\1\s\DtlTest.trx;]
2017-07-14T18:39:50.4472457Z ##[debug]task result: Succeeded
2017-07-14T18:39:50.4472457Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Publish Test Results task search `.trx` only in `d:\a\1\s\D‌​tlTest.trx`. So please check your settings of the task. You can change the **Test results files** as `**\*.trx` and queue the build again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marina,  I figured the issue, its not this task rather one task before where it was storing the downloaded file from Azure. The destination downloaded path was showing as "d:\a\1\s\D‌​tlTest.trx" where D‌​tlTest.trx was it self a directory. To debug this issue I added another Powershell task to show the file attribute of the destination path and it was showing as "d-----".  This issue is resolved.

Comment: You can write another answer for how to resolve it, and mark your answer 24 hours later.